# AJAX FormData POST not working: Payload not delivered to PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm trying to send a form when the button "agregar-carrito" gets clicked, creating the form structure inside the .js, and sending it in directed to a .php page named "carrito.php" with POST as REQUEST_METHOD, but the .php page doesnt seem to get the payload from the AJAX. From the page where the data is getting delivered seems to be delivering the data just fine, the payload is sent with the following General Headers data:

```
Request URL: http://localhost/HC/carrito.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

but on the other end, carrito.php doesnt seem to get sent anything. Without the echos handling the warnings, it results with the following error:

> PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "REQUEST_METHOD" in D:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\HC\carrito.php on line 3

**script.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Manejar el evento clic del botón "Agregar al carrito"
  $('#agregar-carrito').on('click', function(e) {
    // Obtener los datos del producto
    var cantidad = $('#cantidad').val();
    var nombreProducto = $('#nombre-producto').text();
    var idProducto = $('html').attr('id');
    var precioUnitarioTexto = $('#precio-unitario').text();
    precioUnitarioTexto = precioUnitarioTexto.replace(' MXN', '');
    precioUnitarioTexto = precioUnitarioTexto.replace('Precio: $', '');
    var precioUnitario = parseFloat(precioUnitarioTexto);
    var imagenProducto = $('#imagen-producto').attr('src');

    // Calcular el precio total
    var precioTotal = cantidad * precioUnitario;

    // Crear un objeto FormData para enviar los datos del producto (incluyendo la imagen)
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('cantidad', cantidad);
    formData.append('nombre', nombreProducto);
    formData.append('id', idProducto);
    formData.append('imagen', imagenProducto);
    formData.append('precioUnitario', precioUnitario);
    formData.append('precioTotal', precioTotal);

    // Enviar los datos del producto al archivo carrito.php utilizando AJAX
    $.ajax({
      url: 'carrito.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(response) {
        // Manejar la respuesta del servidor (si es necesario)
        console.log(response);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        // Manejar errores de la solicitud AJAX (si es necesario)
        console.error(error);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**carrito.php**

```php
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST') {
    $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $imagen = $_POST['imagen'];
    $precioUnitario = $_POST['precioUnitario'];
    $precioTotal = $_POST['precioTotal'];

    // Realiza cualquier operación adicional con los datos recibidos

    // Ejemplo: Imprime los datos recibidos
    echo "Cantidad: $cantidad, Nombre: $nombre, ID: $id, Imagen: $imagen, Precio Unitario: $precioUnitario, Precio Total: $precioTotal";
} else {
    echo "Método de solicitud incorrecto.";
}
?>
```

EDIT: As requested, heres the var_dump($_SERVER);

```
array(48) { 
["MIBDIRS"]=> string(38) "D:/Program Files/xampp/php/extras/mibs" ["MYSQL_HOME"]=> string(16) "\xampp\mysql\bin" 
["OPENSSL_CONF"]=> string(45) "D:/Program Files/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf" 
["PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR"]=> string(10) "\xampp\php" 
["PHPRC"]=> string(10) "\xampp\php" 
["TMP"]=> string(10) "\xampp\tmp" 
["HTTP_HOST"]=> string(9) "localhost" 
["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=> string(10) "keep-alive" 
["HTTP_SEC_CH_UA"]=> string(66) ""Microsoft Edge";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"" 
["HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_MOBILE"]=> string(2) "?0" ["HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_PLATFORM"]=> string(9) ""Windows"" ["HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS"]=> string(1) "1" ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=> string(129) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/113.0.1774.50" 
["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=> string(124) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7" ["HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE"]=> string(11) "same-origin" ["HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE"]=> string(8) "navigate" ["HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER"]=> string(2) "?1" ["HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST"]=> string(8) "document" ["HTTP_REFERER"]=> string(45) "http://localhost/HC/detalle_producto.php?id=2" ["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=> string(17) "gzip, deflate, br" ["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=> string(14) "en-US,en;q=0.9" 
["SystemRoot"]=> string(10) "C:\WINDOWS" ["COMSPEC"]=> string(27) "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" 
["PATHEXT"]=> string(53) ".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC" ["WINDIR"]=> string(10) "C:\WINDOWS" 
["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=> string(94) "
Apache/2.4.56 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1t PHP/8.2.4 Server at localhost Port 80" 
["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=> string(46) "Apache/2.4.56 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1t PHP/8.2.4" 
["SERVER_NAME"]=> string(9) "localhost" ["SERVER_ADDR"]=> string(3) "::1" 
["SERVER_PORT"]=> string(2) "80" ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=> string(3) "::1" 
["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(29) "D:/Program Files/xampp/htdocs" 
["REQUEST_SCHEME"]=> string(4) "http" ["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]=> string(0) "" 
["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(29) "D:/Program Files/xampp/htdocs" 
["SERVER_ADMIN"]=> string(20) "postmaster@localhost" 
["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=> string(44) 
 "D:/ProgramFiles/xampp/htdocs/HC/carrito.php" 
["REMOTE_PORT"]=> string(5) "54547" 
["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=> string(7) "CGI/1.1" 
["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=> string(8) "HTTP/1.1" 
["REQUEST_METHOD"]=> string(3) "GET" 
["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(0) "" 
["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(15) "/HC/carrito.php" 
["SCRIPT_NAME"]=> string(15) "/HC/carrito.php" 
["PHP_SELF"]=> string(15) "/HC/carrito.php" 
["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]=> float(1684970935.633346) 
["REQUEST_TIME"]=> int(1684970935) }
```

I dont get why is showing "GET".

EDIT: Here's the rest of the HTML, it contains many info coming from my db, hope is not overwhelming. It gets the details of a product registered on the database by the productID.

**detalle_producto.php**

```
<?php
// Obtener el ID del producto desde la URL
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $productId = $_GET['id'];

  // Consulta a la base de datos para obtener los detalles del producto
  // Reemplaza 'nombre_servidor', 'nombre_usuario', 'contraseña' y 'bd_heladeria' con tus propios valores
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "db_heladeria";

  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  if (!$conn) {
    die("Error de conexión: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  $sql = "SELECT nombre, precio, tipo, imagen, id_prod FROM productos WHERE id_prod = $productId";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // Mostrar los detalles del producto
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $productID = $row['id_prod'];
    $productName = $row['nombre'];
    $productPrice = $row['precio'];
    $productType = $row['tipo'];
    $productImage = $row['imagen'];

    // Cerrar la conexión a la base de datos
    mysqli_close($conn);
  } else {
    // No se encontró el producto correspondiente al ID
    mysqli_close($conn);
    echo "Producto no encontrado.";
    exit;
  }
} else {
  // No se proporcionó ningún ID de producto en la URL
  echo "ID de producto no válido.";
  exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="<?php echo $productID?>">
<head>
  <title>Detalles del Producto</title>
  <!-- Aquí incluye tus estilos CSS y archivos JavaScript -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="detalle_script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <nav>
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="logo">
          <h1><a href="index.html">Heladeria Cajeme</a></h1>
        </div>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="helados.php">Helados</a></li>
          <li><a href="paletas.php">Paletas</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="cart">
          <a href="carrito.php" class="cart-button">Carrito de compras</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="product-details-container">
    <div class="product-image-container">
      <!-- Muestra la imagen del producto -->
      <img id="imagen-producto" src="<?php echo $productImage; ?>" alt="<?php echo $productName; ?>" onerror="this.src='default.jpg'"/>
    </div>
    <div class="product-details">
      <!-- Muestra los detalles del producto -->
      <h2 id="nombre-producto"><?php echo $productName; ?></h2>
      <p id="precio-unitario">Precio: $<?php echo $productPrice; ?>.00 MXN</p>
      <p>Tipo: <?php echo $productType; ?></p>
      <!-- Campo para ingresar la cantidad deseada -->
      <div class="product-sum">
      <label for="cantidad">Cantidad:</label>
      <input type="number" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" min="1" value="1">
      <!-- Botón "Agregar al carrito" -->
      <button class="add-to-cart-button" id="agregar-carrito">Agregar al carrito</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <div class="footer-grid">
      <div class="footer-logo">
        <h1>Heladeria Cajeme</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-links">
        <a href="helados.php">Helados</a>
        <a href="paletas.php">Paletas</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using WordPress? See https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-warning-undefined-array-key-request_method/

Comment: No, im coding it all with VSCode.

Comment: It seems very odd for `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to not be set, especially considering it looks like you're using XAMPP. Can you try adding some debugging like `var_dump($_SERVER);` at the top of your `carrito.php` file and [edit] your question with the output?

Comment: Also, depending on what sort of element `#agregar-carrito` is, you may need to add `e.preventDefault()` into your _click_ event handler

Comment: Sure, theres the edit! somehow the request method is GET instead of POST, im not seeing whats the problem.

Comment: And #agregar-carrito comes from a simple button (Not input > submit), and waits for a click, i tried to put the `e.preventDefault()` line below `var precioTotal = cantidad * precioUnitario;` but nothing changes.

Comment: _"And #agregar-carrito comes from a simple button (Not input > submit)"_ - a `button` without a `type` attribute (if that's what you are talking about) would _still_ be a submit button.

Comment: WordPress isn't an IDE that you code with, it's an application framework.

Comment: Something is not adding up here. You cannot have `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` be both unset _and_ equal to "GET". Also, I asked you to use `var_dump($_SERVER)`. Please [edit] your question with the code you're currently using. Also include the relevant HTML

Comment: I was clarifying the button type, i thought i'd be relevant the distinction.

Comment: And i have no problem showing the HTML (on a php page just like carrito.php), just that is kind of long. i'll try to showcase the important section.

Comment: The error message you say you're seeing does not align with the debugging `var_dump()` output. What **exactly** is the error you're seeing and perhaps more importantly, where do you see it; in the console from `console.log(response)` or directly in the browser main window?

Comment: Edit's up! I added the .php file content and updated the var_dump(_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) to var_dump(_SERVER)

Comment: The idea is sending all the info from `detalle_producto.php` to `carrito.php` using ajax, all fine from the `detalle_producto.php` side, the payload sends just fine, but when i go to `carrito.php` to see the checkout, it echoes the `echo "Método de solicitud incorrecto.";.` but without it, gives me the following Warning `PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "REQUEST_METHOD" in D:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\HC\carrito.php on line 3`

Comment: _"when i go to carrito.php"_... what exactly do you mean by this? How are you _going_ there?

Comment: If im not being clear, let me know!

Comment: On the navbar of `detalle_producto.php` i have a option called "Carrito de compras" that has a href to `carrito.php` and i use that button to open carrito.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to solve it. In the PHP on the server-side, when you request the POST data, use [php://input](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input) to retrieve the form data like so:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$cantidad = $data['cantidad'];
```

Comment: OP is sending the request body as `multipart/form-data`, not `application/json`

Comment: My apologies, you are correct.